# Creating a process to filter Specific Data via Rows and Columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to help a colleague with some work in Excel, he has a data-set of 40 Organisations of which each organisation has multiple Key Personal (KP). For each of these KP there has been an assessment against 3 key areas of criteria (where they are given a Y or N), these criterion being:

- Geographic Area (Broken down into 26 Geographic Areas)
- Industry Experience (Broken down into 18 Industries)
- Areas of Expertise (Broken down into 18 Areas)

An example of the data is shown in the screenshot is linked
[image: Example Data]

What I am trying to achieve is set up a 'filter form' that will allow an individual to put in their requirements (e.g. Aged Care Experience, in All of the West Region) and be provided with an output of the organisations that fit this criteria.

I have attempted to achieve this via utilizing a Pivot table, but have had no luck due to the different criteria and the fact that each organisation has multiple KP.

Any assistance would be much appreciated as to whether this can actually be achieved in Excel and how it could be done. If it can't I was thinking whether an Access Database could be used.

**Update**:
Please see attached the example data extract as requested by donPablo
[Data Extract](https://ufile.io/ce5ie)

From discussions with my Colleague the best outcome for him would be to get the Supplier, The KP and the other Criteria (think of it as filtering to hide all the Organisations and KPs expect the ones that meet the criteria).

if this is not achievable I can imagine that having the name of the organisation and KP as the output (that meet the criteria) would be suffice.

Comment: Please show us the required output layout.  Just a list of Orgs?  or also KP-s? or also all of the other Criteria where they have Y????  Secondly, please export (a subset of ) the XLS as CSV and post that file, so that we have some data to use in development of a solution for you.

Comment: Hi donPablo, I have edited my original post with a link to an extract of the data and my ideas around the output. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will need to create the Excel Form that has 3 drop-down lists (Geo, Industry, Expertise).  btw, can users select only ONE in each area? or can users select MULTIPLE in each area?  (eg Geelong and Hamilton in one search, rather than two searches)(Aged care and Child care)(and NOTHING in expertise ??, then what??Must they select something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Think about maintenance of the ExampleData...
Adding a new Industry.  Adding a new Expertise.
Splitting Industry into 3 Industry-s

Adding new Org with 2 KP
Deleting old KP3 from an org

For now with the initial concept, changes are small.
But soon in growth period there will be many changes.
How do you distribute these changes to all the users?

Thus, some sort of Split solution is needed.
A back-end DB (XLS or MSACCESS or SQLSERVER) ,
and a front-end form for--
  Selection(s)
  Results

Back-end as XLS could still be as ExampleData...
To be kept in central office.
And a front-end that links or references that db
  but does not contain all the detail rows.

I think that the main matrix needs another column
  called  AreaType, value  G or I or E
  and that the area heading row needs to say
  'ANY Geo" and have all "Y"-s in each column,  etc for I and E.
In searching the matrix for Aged Care we should only look at Industry.
The ANY row would be chosen when the user does not choose an area.

I think that "Org" is a separate table
And that "KP" is another separate table.
This allows full details to be stored elsewhere
  than the main matrix of areas.
Column heading of matrix would be "Org#~KP#", which would be
  parsed on the tilde and separately looked up.
  (it is improbable that any org or kp will have a tilde).


Yes, it is possible to search the matrix and retrieve qualified rows.

For ncol = minCol to maxCol
    CountYInG = 0: CountYInI = 0: CountYInE = 0: 
    For each AreaType G, I, E
        ' then look at what was selected  (gggg/iiii/eeee)
        For each AreaName in (gggg/iiii/eeee)
            If matrix = "Y" then add 1 to Count
        next
    next
    if CountYInG > 0 and CountYInI > 0 and CountYInE > 0 then
        This Org/KP qualifies
    endif
next
```

> > added Pi Day, 20:00
> >     First inclination is NOT to have 3 criteria tables (G/I/E), but rather ONE table.

Lets make several alternative DB designs.  Then look at usage, and rank them.
Finally choose one and do it.  Good luck, and Bye.

```
Matrix alternative
MatrixTable--AreaType & AreaName (PK), and one attribute Column for each Org/KP with value 'Y' or blank.
  1st row has PK=C-ColHeadings, and each Column has Org#/KP# for that column.
OrgTable--Org# (PK), and OrgName, OrgStreet1, OrgStreet2, OrgCity/State/Zip, OrgPhone, ...
KPTable --KP# (PK),  and KPName, KPOrg#, KPPhone

Normalized alternative  (Admin would need to do pivot to see matrix view)
DetailTable--Org#(FK)-KP#(FK)-AreaType-AreaName(FK) DetailValue = 'Y'  or ('Y' by implication of row existance)
OrgTable--Org# (PK), and OrgName, OrgStreet1, OrgStreet2, OrgCity/State/Zip, OrgPhone, ...
KPTable --KP# (PK),  and KPName, KPOrg#, KPPhone
AreaTable--AreaType-AreaName(PK)  (so that everyone spells it the same)


Your favorite design... list the tables, and their fields
```

Comment: Hi donPablo, For the next 2 years the only change that would occur would that organisations/KP may be removed, it is highly unlikely any would be added until a review is undertaken. My understanding is that an Access Database should work, although my knowledge of Access is limited. I'm struggling to understand how the Tables would be designed, what the keys would be and how the relationships would work. I.e. I can create 3 tables (Geo, Industry and Expertise) with 'Org-KP' as the key for each table with the relationship between 'Org-KP' in each Table. i am unsure if this is correct